# Bitmap Memory Error with sampleSize

Tags: android-studio, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have created a 2d game, i released it on the play store and it doesn't open on mobile phones (for some reason it works perfectly fine on tablets). I found that the problem was to do with bitmap Memory issue so i did my research and tried multiple solutions.

I tried:

```
largeHeap = true;
```

this allowed it to work on tablets

I used this (from the docs https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) to load bitmaps more effectively:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
```

After implementing this i saw a huge change in the processing speed, changing to a new scene was 10 times faster.

But still this didn't fix my problem. But i realised that after opening the app a white screen would appear and it would take longer for the app to crash.

so i have a few questions:

Firstly, i was wondering whether ALL bitmaps in my drawable folder are loaded in at once (even if they are not being called). Because my apps first scene (which is only 1 bitmap) doesn't even load before crashing with memory error. I do have about 250 images in the drawable folder, about 10 bitmaps on each scene excluding the first scene.

Secondly, does the following code create two instances of the same bitmap in the memory(normal bitmap and resized bitmap). If it does how can i avoid this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.image, 100, 100);

Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 6, Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 6, true);
```

Lastly, i read about bitmap.recyle and bitmap=null, do i need to use these if i am planning on reusing the bitmaps when the user returns to that specific scene.

I hope you can help in any way possible, if it be giving me a possible solutions or even pointing me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally got it to work. I simply halved the size of all 250 bitmaps which solved the problem. But because of this, the quality of the bitmaps became mediocre.